# trouble storing pointers in an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, text-files

I want to read a file line by line. Each line consists of 504 entries. I want to store from each line the first column in an array `array1` the second in an array `array2` and the third one in an array called `array3`. The last 500 entries I want to store in an 2D array `array4`.

For now I tried to do this with pointers but I have trouble to store them right.

```
vrFile = fopen("file.txt","r");

    int size = 1024, pos;
    int c, cdbz;
    char *buffervr = (char *)malloc(size);
    char *bufferdbz = (char *)malloc(size);
    int lin=0;
    char *array1, *array2, *array3, **array4;
    array1=(char *) malloc(5000*sizeof(double));
    array2=(char *) malloc(5000*sizeof(double));
    array3=(char *) malloc(5000*sizeof(double));

    array4 = malloc(5000 * sizeof(double *));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    array4[i] = malloc(nbins * sizeof(double));
    }

    tdbz = malloc(5000 * sizeof(double *));
    for(i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    tdbz[i] = malloc(500 * sizeof(double));
    }

    if(vrFile!=NULL) {
      do { // read all lines in file
        pos = 0;
        do{ // read one line
            c = fgetc(vrFile);
          if(c != EOF) buffervr[pos++] = (char)c;
          if(pos >= size - 1) { // increase buffer length - leave room for 0
            size *=2;
            buffervr = (char*)realloc(buffervr, size);
          }
        }while(c != EOF && c != '\n');
        buffervr[pos] = 0;
        // line is now in buffer
        //printf("%s",buffervr);
        char *ptr;
        ptr = strtok(buffervr," \t");
        int abs=1;
        while(ptr != NULL) {
            if(abs==1){
                array1[lin] = ptr;
            }
            else if(abs==2) {
                array2[lin] = atof(ptr);
            }
            else if (abs==3) {
                array3[lin] = atof(ptr);
            }
            else {
                array4[lin][abs-4]=atof(ptr);
            }
            abs++;

            ptr = strtok(NULL, " \t");

        }
            lin++;
      } while(c != EOF);
      fclose(vrFile);
    }
    free(buffervr);
```

My Problem is, that when I print out `ptr` with `printf("%s\n",ptr)` I get the right number, e.g. the first entry from the first line is displayed (0.52312) . But when I try assign `array1[lin]` to `ptr` I get an warning:

```
"assingnment makes integer from pointer without a cast"

printf("%i\n",array1[lin])
```

results in: "96"

Has someone an idea why this happens and how I can manage to read and save the floating-point entries of each line in different arrays?

Thank you!

Comment: Please make a sscce Answer. There's too much code here. http://sscce.org/

Comment: If you want to store `double` elements why are you declaring `array1` as `char *` and not `double *`?

Comment: when I declare array1 with double *array1; And try to read with array1[lin]=ptr; I get a strange number as well (-134258688)?! Don't know where this comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
array1[lin] = ptr;
```

The compiler kind of tells it all: `array1[lin]` is a `char` and `ptr` is a `char*`.

Comment: okay, thank you. and how do I solve this? I thought I declared array1 as array of char* ?!

Comment: `char* array1[MAX_ELEMENTS]` or `char** array1` and them `malloc`.

Comment: Oh I just found out - unfortunately it did not work all good. When I print out e.g. array1[lin] in the moment I assign it to ptr then it works -BUT when I than do a for loop and want to print out everything that is in array[1] with for(i=0,i<lins,i++) printf("%s",array[i]); then nothing is printed out (just an empty line?!)